# API for displaying video and drawing 2D elements

Tags: windows, api, video, 2d, draw

I'm looking for a Windows library/SDK that will allow me to do the following:

- Display video from a network stream
- Draw 2D elements on the displayed image in real time, such as lines, circles, text, etc.
- Use it in a commercial application (I don't mind paying for it)

I'm willing to use any programming language or environment so there's no specific requirement, except for the Windows OS.
Which library/SDK would you recommend considering the requirements from above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many solutions and found that the best one for me is to use WPF with [WPF MediaKit](http://www.codeplex.com/WPFMediaKit). A video element is placed inside a Canvas, which makes it possible to add other graphic elements on top of the video (basically every WPF UI element).

Although I really tried, I couldn't draw on VLC video using QGraphicsView.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [VLC](http://wiki.videolan.org/Developers_Corner) one to display video from a network stream.

For 2D elements you can use the [Qt framework](http://qt.nokia.com/developer).

In addition VLC is developped with Qt. So sure to not have problem by using VLC and Qt in your project.

Comment: Is it really possible to use Qt to draw directly on the VLC video?

Comment: The VLC library allows you to display a video in a QWidget. Then you can do all you want with this QWidget. Assuming you will use the QGraphicsView (that inherits from QWidget), you will have facilities to manage 2D elements.

Comment: Personnaly I would display the video in a QWidget and add a QGraphicsView with a transparent background above.